# Android - The application crashes randomly

Tags: java, android, kotlin, crash

I've been dealing with this problem for about 3 months now and I haven't been able to fix it in any way. The app crashes on its own with nothing. Usually I am loading many images in recyclerview on the page where it crashes. But sometimes it can crash anywhere.

Emulator API Level: 29
SDK: 11 - Current

```
com.example.example A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4 in tid 20623 (HeapTaskDaemon), pid 20608 (om.example.example)
 A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:10/QSR1.200715.002/6695061:userdebug/dev-keys'
 A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
 A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
 A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2021-03-09 03:33:32+0300
 A/DEBUG: pid: 20608, tid: 20623, name: HeapTaskDaemon  >>> com.example.example <<<
 A/DEBUG: uid: 10134
 A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4
 A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
 A/DEBUG:     eax c1d23f80  ebx eb530a74  ecx 00000000  edx 00000000
 A/DEBUG:     edi 00000000  esi c6711080
 A/DEBUG:     ebp c6710fb8  esp c6710e40  eip eb4190d8
 com.example.example E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
 A/DEBUG: backtrace:
 A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 0058e0d8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12StackVisitor9WalkStackILNS0_16CountTransitionsE1EEEvb+1880) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 005c278e  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (void art::Thread::VisitRoots<false>(art::RootVisitor*)+3534) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 0024c358  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::CaptureThreadRootsForMarkingAndCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+216) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 005cb034  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+1556) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 0023a5f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::CaptureThreadRootsForMarking()+164) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 00235561  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::MarkingPhase()+1265) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 002344b2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::RunPhases()+258) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 00257520  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::GarbageCollector::Run(art::gc::GcCause, bool)+448) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 0027c4d3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::CollectGarbageInternal(art::gc::collector::GcType, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+3027) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 0029185e  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGC(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+126) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 00298643  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGCTask::Run(art::Thread*)+51) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 002cec1d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+61) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 004a3a05  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::VMRuntime_runHeapTasks(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+53) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 0004d138  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+104) (BuildId: 6e90a1c34e5945941f1d1cb9bac9218325a4cd49)
 A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 0013e7d2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 00149a69  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+281) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 00332502  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+386) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 0032c19c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+988) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 006818dd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+989) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 00138821  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
1615250012.158 20838-20838/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 001b404a  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal+38)
 A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 00681b4c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1612) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #22 pc 00138821  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #23 pc 001b382e  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+50)
 A/DEBUG:       #24 pc 0068382c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1980) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #25 pc 00138a21  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+33) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #26 pc 000ea918  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Thread.run+8)
 A/DEBUG:       #27 pc 002f8e0a  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.1175793267244191248+298) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #28 pc 002ffcc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+181) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #29 pc 0066fc49  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1209) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #30 pc 0014503d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #31 pc 0013e7d2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #32 pc 00149a69  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+281) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #33 pc 0055a563  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+99) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #34 pc 0055b96a  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+474) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #35 pc 005aaac1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1585) (BuildId: fe49ff2b6f401678e4775fb2121e4ea4)
 A/DEBUG:       #36 pc 0011a8e5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53) (BuildId: 471745f0fbbcedb3db1553d5bd6fcd8b)
 A/DEBUG:       #37 pc 000af6a7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71) (BuildId: 471745f0fbbcedb3db1553d5bd6fcd8b)
system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
com.example.example E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01
system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '36d5ed1 com.example.example/com.example.example.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: Have you check out this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout

Comment: This error does not seem to cause the crash. The problem is not related to recyclerview in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Although not sure, this error may be related to Database Inspector. If your application quits with no errors, close and reopen android studio and do not click on the database inspector tab. For me, the error seems to be fixed now.